# Android not loading typeface from LocalApplicationDirectory

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, typeface

I've created a custom renderer for Xamarin Labels, and i'm trying to use this to set the typeface.

The typeface is saved to 
`Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData`

When i load it with `Typeface.CreateFromFile(path)` it doesn't show any exception or warning, but the label is just rendered with the default typeface.

Is it at all possible to load a .ttf file form outside the Assets folder?

Comment: you could save the font into external storage

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

From **Assets** folder:

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Android.App.Application.Context.Assets, "sampleFontFamily.ttf");
```

Outside Assets folder, let's say from **Resources** (Resources->Font->myfont.ttf):

```
Typeface tf = ResourcesCompat.GetFont(Android.App.Application.Context, Resource.Font.myfont);
```

Apply this typeface object to your label.

Comment: I'm really looking to load a font from *outside* of the assets

Comment: Updated my answer, you can load from Resources folder

Answer (score 0):

> Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData

You're saving your typeface file to internal storage(the files directory). The Files directory is a private directory that is only accessible by your application. Neither the user or the OS can access this file. You'll have to save the file in either [Public External Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/files/external-storage?tabs=macos#public-external-files) or [Private External Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/files/external-storage?tabs=macos#private-external-files).